# Why do I get these odd foot prints from JLCPCB - 0602 and 1206

Tags: pcb, footprint, routing

Why do I get these foot prints from JLCPCB?

The parts are regular 0602 and 1206 and capacitors.

I'm using KiCad 5.1.7. No external libraries. Everything is default.

[image]

My GerbView:

[image]

Comment: ask them, maybe? It's their script.

Comment: Look at the Gerber files in Gerbview. It looks like software to round the corner ) went C instead. If all else fails, is there an option to use pads without rounded corners? But if teh Gerbers are OK you should be good to go.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Hang on a minute! I will check!

Comment: @BrianDrummond I cannot see the pads in GerbView. But how can I remove the C in these corner?

Comment: The corners are correctly rounded on the 1206 footprints (confirming my guess). But the tracks are too big on the 0603s so the pads are swallowed up in the end of the track. But worse, there's no thermal relief around pads on the ground plane, which is a separate/bigger problem.

Comment: 3 ways to remove the C-shaped bites : 1) ask JLCPCB to fix their viewer. 2) Use footprints with rectangular pads (design them yourself if necessary : designing footprints is just part of the job) 3) Ignore the viewer problem and get the Gerbers to look right : that's usually what PCBs are made from.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks. The tracks need to be large (1mm) because it going to flow high current there. But I think I will re-design these footprints to square shaped.

Comment: I have necked the last mm of tracks down a size or two where they join too small pads. Whether that's worth doing is opinion.

Comment: @BrianDrummond It works by using retangular pads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the JLCPCB renderer. They do not correctly render pads with rounded corners.
I have several boards made via JLCPCB, and they all have been produced correctly.
You may ignore this rendering glitch.